# Operating Systems used by AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-rds

What operating systems does Amazon RDS use. While I understand that when using RDS we are just exposed to a endpoint and internally the database we use might be supported by multiple systems, I would like to know what is the OS used by those systems.

Answer (score 6):

To check the underlying operating of your MySQL DB instance on AWS RDS, you can use the following command:

```
mysql> SHOW variables LIKE '%version%';
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.39                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.39-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those systems are running under the Amazon Linux Distribution